# Implementing the Template Method pattern in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, template-method-pattern

The *template method* pattern provides that the abstract base class has a not overridable method: this method implements the common algorithm and should not overridden in the subclasses. In Java the template method is declared `final` within the abstract base class, in C# the `sealed` keyword has a similar meaning, but a not overridden method can not be declared `sealed`.

```
public abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract AlgorithmStep1();

    protected abstract AlgorithmStep2();

    public sealed void TemplateMethod()   // sealed: compile error
    {
        AlgorithmStep1();
        AlgorithmStep2();
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?
Why can not prevent a method can be overridden by subclasses (in C#)?

Comment: You can only seal overridden members. The lack of the keyword `abstract` or `virtual` means that the method is already sealed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`sealed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) modifier is only valid for function members which are overriding base class members, to stop them from being virtual for derived classes. Function members are non-virtual by default in C# (unlike Java). You still need the `sealed` modifier for a *class* though - classes aren't sealed by default.

Just remove the `sealed` modifier from your method and it should be fine.

See section 10.6.5 of the C# 4 spec for more details about sealed methods (sealed properties and events are in section 10.7.5 and 10.8.4 respectively).

> When an instance method declaration includes a `sealed` modifier, that method is said to be a sealed method. If an instance method declaration includes the `sealed` modifier, it must also include the `override` modifier. Use of the `sealed` modifier prevents a derived class from further overriding the method.

Comment: Ok, it works correctly by removing the `sealed` keyword, but I thought that there was some mechanism (such as the `final` keyword in Java) that _prevents you from hiding the inherited method_. I wonder, out of curiosity, the reason for which this mechanism is not present.

Comment: @enzom83: No, you can always *hide* the inherited method - but you can't override it, so anyone calling `TemplateMethod` on an expression of static type `Base` will always call the right method.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `sealed` keyword. By default, methods are not overridable; subclasses cannot override them, only hide them.

Answer (score 1):

C# methods are sealed by default